# how to redirect the clients to different URL?

Tags: c, sockets, redirect

I want to redirect the clients who are accessing my port 80 to some URL[Ex: www.google.com]. And the Redirected URL need to be changed in the browser address bar also.

Currently I'm using the following code,

```
#include<netinet/in.h>    
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>    
#include<sys/stat.h>    
#include<sys/types.h>    
#include<unistd.h>    

int main() {    
int create_socket, new_socket;    
socklen_t addrlen;    
int bufsize = 1024;    
char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);    
struct sockaddr_in address;    

if ((create_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) > 0){    
  printf("The socket was created\n");
}

address.sin_family = AF_INET;    
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    
address.sin_port = htons(15000);    

if (bind(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address)) == 0){    
  printf("Binding Socket\n");
}


while (1) {    
  if (listen(create_socket, 10) < 0) {    
     perror("server: listen");    
     exit(1);    
  }    

  if ((new_socket = accept(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addrlen)) <  
0) {    
     perror("server: accept");    
     exit(1);    
  }    

  if (new_socket > 0){    
     printf("The Client is connected...\n");
  }

  recv(new_socket, buffer, bufsize, 0);    
  printf("%s\n", buffer);    
  write(new_socket, "hello world\n", 12);    
  close(new_socket);    
}    
close(create_socket);    
return 0;    
}
```

This code only prints hello world in the browser window. But what i need is, the client should be redirect to some other URL and the redirected URL should be changed in the client browser address bar... how can i achieve this?.. Please provide sample code...

Comment: See [HTTP 303 redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303).

Comment: A side note: You check for some functions to return okay (i.e. your `bind` call) but not for them to return an error? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

change:-

```
write(new_socket, "hello world\n", 12);
```

to

```
write(new_socket, "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nLocation: http://www.google.com\r\n <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\"><html><head><title>Your Page Title</title><meta http-equiv=\"REFRESH\" content=\"0;url=http://www.google.com\"></HEAD><BODY>Optional page text here.</BODY></HTML>", 326);
```

Comment: @user1216216 try the changed version, I forgot the header.

Comment: I have replaced the given code its working fine . But the same code with port other than 80 is not working. If i changed the port to 8181 its just showing the html in the browser. how to make it work for different ports?..

Comment: I have replaced the given code its working fine . I am facing two problems.
1. If I use ports other than 80 its not redirecting.
2. When access from Other machines its not redirected.

Please provide solution for these..

Comment: I have already told its because your code is not listening on other port.try doing ls /proc

Comment: I got some list of processid and files.. please tel me what can i do with those things?... and when I enter the command netstat -na | grep "80" its showing
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0* LISTEN  ... what does it mean?..

Comment: 1. If I use port 8888 its not redirecting. Its showing the string whatever available in side the write function. 
2. When access from Other machines its not redirecting.
Please provide solution for these things..

Comment: when accessing from local machine use http://127.0.0.1:8888/ and from other machine http://serverip:8888/ and it should work, if not then obiviously there is some huge fault.